# Twitter API request won't authenticate on Express App

Tags: express, authentication, twitter, routes, request

My Node Express App successfully runs my **routes/index.js** and **routes/users.js** files on *localhost:3001* and *localhost:3001/users* respectively.

I'd now like to make a request to Twitter's user_timeline API endpoint and render the response (tweet data) to localhost:3001/tweets. Currently, I receive the error:

{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}

I've doubled checked my Auth keys and they all seem correct. Maybe it has something to do with an unauthenticated preflight request being sent prior my tweets request(?).

**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/*middleware CORS headers, allow node data to load from different port*/
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**routes/users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json([{
    "id":1,
    "username":"samsepi0l"
    },
    {
    "id":2,
    "username":"D0loresH4ze"
  }]);
});

module.exports = router;
```

**routes/tweets.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var router = express.Router();
var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
  access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  client.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name: 'nodejs', count: 20 }, function(error, tweets, response) {
    if (!error) {
      res.status(200).render('index', { title: 'Express', tweets: tweets });
    }
    else {
      res.status(500).json({ error: error });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/tweets', tweets);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-backend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5",
    "twitter": "^1.7.1"
  }    
}
```

Comment: can you add server.js code?

Comment: Added app.js (which I think is the file you're asking for).  Please note: The error has changed, as I subsequently added the '/tweets' route to app.js